# I am trying to create a Manual Workflow in Github actions which will run based on inputs given. But it doesn't seems to work. What's wrong?

Tags: github, github-actions

Based on the inputs, I have used *ifs* for input based run as below:

`name: Deploy to Coach Retail Layer0 if: ${{ github.events.inputs.coachRetail == 'true' }} run: | npm run edgio:deploy coach-pwa -- ${{'--branch=$BRANCH_NAME' || ''}} --token=xdn_deploy_token --environment=${{github.events.inputs.env}} npm run edgio:deploy ca.coach.com -- ${{'--branch=$BRANCH_NAME' || ''}} --token=layer0_deploy_token_coach_canada --environment=${{github.events.inputs.env}}`

But it skips this and throws an exception as:
`Event Validation Error: The event type workflow_dispatch is not supported. Only push, pull_request events are supported at this time.`

What am I doing wrong here?